# How do I customize the documentation blocks Enterprise Architect Generates?

Tags: modeling, enterprise-architect

I'm using Enterprise Architect to model my software and to generate code skeletons. As part of this process, the tool will automatically add documentation blocks for classes, functions, and data members. This is fine, but I don't see any obvious way to customize the output. For example, this is what comes out for class Foo:

```
/**
 * Text from the properties window in EA for Foo. 
 * @author My Name
 * @version 1.0
 * @created 26-Oct-2017 12:32:57
 */
class Foo
{
```

I've looked through the Code Template Editor but things like this all seem to be hidden behind a magic function. For example, the C++ Class Notes template includes `%JAVADOC_COMMENT($wrapLen)` but I haven't seen where I can have any effect on what goes in that comment.

Is there a way to customize JavaDoc output in EA? Or perhaps to define my own "Comment Style"? For example, maybe I want to switch the order in which items are displayed, I want to add some blank lines in between parameters, or I want to eliminate `@created` from my documentation blocks altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *magic function* you are referring too is a [documented](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/13.5/model_domains/functionmacros.html) macro:

> **JAVADOC_COMMENT([wrap_length])**
>   Converts the notes for the element currently in scope to javadoc -style comments.

So you won't be able to tweak the way the macro works.
But you can of course replace the standard macro with your own comment section, if you really think that is worth it.

Comment: I'd seen the JAVADOC_COMMENT() in the code generation templates but I appreciate your confirmation that it's not something that can be tweaked.